# Convergence from above problem

Tags: measure-theory

I don't know if this problem can be solved by Extended Dominated Convergence Theorem. Could anyone help me with this problem?

[image]

This is a question from a sample exam.

Comment: **Hint**: Consider ${f_n}^+$ and  $f^+ $ and apply the  Dominated Convergence Theorem. Consider ${f_n}^-$ and  $f^-$ and apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Use the fact that $\int {f_n}^+ d\mu$ and $\int f^+ d\mu$ are necessarily finite to conclude that 
$$ \int f_n d\mu=  \left (\int {f_n}^+ d\mu -\int {f_n}^- d\mu \right ) \: \downarrow \: \left (\int f^+ d\mu -\int f^- d\mu \right ) = \int f d\mu $$
So, in this approach, we use both the  Dominated Convergence Theorem and the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: **Hint 2**: To use only the Monotone Convergence Theorem, note that, for each $n\geq 1$,  $f_1-f_n \geq 0$  and $ f_1-f_n \uparrow f_1-f$. Apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem and get 
$$ \int (f_1 -f_n) d\mu\: \uparrow \: \int (f_1- f) d\mu $$
use the fact that $\int f_1 d\mu$ is finite to conclude that  $ \int f_n d\mu\, \downarrow \, \int f d\mu $.

Comment: Got it! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just let $g_n=-f_n$, and use Levi monotone convergence theorem on $g_n$, you can get the result.

Comment: We can not simply let $g_n=-f_n$ and use the Monotone Convergence Theorem on $g_n$, because we don't know that $g_n \geq 0$. (See my comment **Hint2** under the question).